# How to send multiple values from a single php script to c# client

Tags: c#, php

I had a php script that returns a value to a c# client.

```
<?php

//catching data from client
$name=strtoupper(strip_tags($_POST['name']));

if($name)//checking if data is not empty
{
    ($connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")) or die("Host Connection Failed");//Unsuccessful Registration

    (mysql_select_db("hello")) or die("Database Selection Failed");//Unsuccessful Registration

    //inserting values
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$name')");

    //getting the id of last inserted row
    $id=mysql_insert_id();

    if($id)
        die("$id");//Successful Registration.
    else
        die("Registration Failed");//Unsuccessful Registration
}
else
    die("Incomplete Details");//Unsuccessful Registration

?>
```

The above script works fine and the $id returned to c# client can be easily used at the client end for the further code at client's side.

But the problem is what if I have to return more than one values and use them at the client's side for the further code. For instance, say I have to return id, location and age to the c# client, so how can I accomplish this?

I mean if I echo out all three values that I have to return, the data will be passed just as a mere string. How are they going to be differentiated?
And what if I want to send an integer like 0 or 1 so that I can switch to the corresponding module at the c# client. Can php return values that are similar in type as that of c# like int, float etc.
What about if I have to send a whole object.

In short, just like I can post more than one values from c# application to php script via GET/POST method. How can I accomplish the same thing in the reverse direction?

Please make me aware wherever I am wrong. I am a beginner to php.

Need help.
Thanks a trillion!
:)

Comment: You should return a JSON string on your PHP script. With JSON you can pass a complete structure of data and read each value separately in C#/PHP. I cannot give you a complete example because I don't know PHP's best practice with JSON, but I'm sure you will find a lot informations about this on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an array rather than a string. The array would hold all the information you needed.

```
$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'location' => $location,
    // etc
);
```

Also remember to move over to `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed.

You also dont need brackets around these lines:

`($connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))`

and

`(mysql_select_db("hello"))`

Comment: I do not have any problem in sending an array or multiple echoes.
The problem is that how the c# client is going to receive that?
The code we are using currently at c# client is something like this:
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    Stream dataStream;
    WebResponse response;
    StreamReader reader;
    
    response = request.GetResponse();
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
Now, here comes the problem.

Comment: I can send name at one time and location at the other time from the same script and the above code can receive them.
But the problem is that how the above code is going to receive both name and location from the response from a single script at a time?
In short, just like as we can post multiple values from c# to php script in a single go and php can receive them without any problem, is there a similar way for the reverse process? So that I can return multiple values at a single go from php script to c# client and c# client can actually catch those values in separate variables just as php does

Comment: One possible approach is to add a special code symbol between name and location to separate the data at client's end using that special symbol, but I want to know what is the optimal way to do this since this approach can have its own limitations?